# Does every universe have Infinity Stones?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, infinity-stones

According to Wong, the Infinity Stones were made by the Big Bang. So in the multiverse, does every universe have Infinity Stones assuming every universe was formed due to their own personal Big Bang?

Answers from the comics or the movies are acceptable.

Comment: "assuming every universe was formed due to their own personal Big Bang" — they might be, although according to _What If...?_, new universes are formed when Peggy Carter somehow chooses not to leave a room, and according to _Loki_, something something Nexus Event. However, those new universes seem to be copies of their "original", so presumably most of them have copies of the Infinity Stones.

Comment: We know that multiple (likely numerous) universes have variants of the Infinity Stones, as we've seen such variants in _Loki_ and _What If...?_. We can't strictly say that every universe within the MCU multiverse has them though, as we don't have information on each and every one one of those universes.

Comment: _"I’m honestly surprised. Didn’t the Watcher warn you? Every universe is different, each one just a fraction unique. Thus the Infinity Stones are unique."_ Seems to imply that every universe has their own Infinity Stones which makes sense when taken into context with _"The Infinity Stones create the experience you know as the flow of time. Remove one of the stones, and the flow splits."_ And also _"Six stones of near unfathomable power. Each controlling an essential aspect of our existence."_ However, I'm not sure if it's enough for an answer.

Comment: The problem comes where we have quotes like _"But in a Multiverse of infinite possibility, is your destiny determined by your nature or by the nature of your world?"_ which would imply it's possible to have a universe without them but that also depends on the context of the quote.

Comment: You need to separate have and had, as the main universe in the MCU does not have them at the moment.

Comment: @DidiKohen It does, they're just not in Stone form. For the purposes of the question though I don't think that particular distinction is really necessary.

Comment: And in [the all-paint universe](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Paint_World), are they made of paint? Is the Soul Stone called the Autumn Glow Stone?

Answer (score 5):

#### Some do, and some... might not.

In alternate universes, such as:

- Earth-838 from *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*
- The universe showed in *What If...?* Episode 2 "What If... T'Challa became Star-Lord?"
- The universe showed in *What If...?* Episode 8 "What If... Ultron Won?"

In addition, in *What If...?* Episode 9 "What If...? the Watcher Broke his Oath?", a multiversal team of heroes is tasked with using the Infinity Crusher to destroy the Infinity Stones held by Ultron. However, it doesn't work, and Ultron says:

> ULTRON: I’m honestly surprised. Didn’t the Watcher warn you? Every universe is different, each one just a fraction unique. **Thus the Infinity Stones are unique.**

This implies that each universe very well could have its own version of Infinity Stones, but they could be *ever-so-slightly* different on a universe-to-universe basis. However, it doesn't necessarily confirm that each one has Infinity Stones. It is enough, however, to surmise that a lot of the universes do. However, we don't have explicit confirmation that they ARE in every universe.

Answer (score 1):

In the comics, many of the multiverses have Infinity Gauntlets.  In a story arc from *Fantastic Four* #570-572 (2010), Earth 616's Reed Richards meets the multiverse "Council of Reeds". His counterparts from alternate Earths are a varied lot, to say the least. As the pages below show, three of them sport Gauntlets.

[image]

[image]

But as was established in many and assorted comic stories, each of the Gauntlets are attuned to their own realities. Outside those realities, they're only pretty stones.
[image]